# regular expression, PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to parce a string like that: `"{data type="subject"}` using regular expressions in PHP.
I've got this:

```
$template = '/{([\w]+)\s([\w]+)="([\w]+)"}/';
```

but nothing happens.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Where do the quote marks start and end? is the first one a part of the string?

Comment: What are you trying to extract from the string? What are you trying to match in the string?

Comment: I'm trying to separate `data`, `type` and `subject`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks fine.
Your pattern:

```
<?php

$s = '{data type="subject"}';
$template = '/{([\w]+)\s([\w]+)="([\w]+)"}/';

preg_match($template, $s, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Result is:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(21) "{data type="subject"}"
  [1] =>
  string(4) "data"
  [2] =>
  string(4) "type"
  [3] =>
  string(7) "subject"
}
```

Show your full example, please.

Comment: Hm, it really does. Probably I made a mistake by myself, thx guys!

Comment: That's right. Please note that `[` `]` are useless around `\w` since you're using a class, not a list of chars.

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces must be escaped. Try something like this :

```
'/\{(\w+)\s(\w+)="(\w+)"\}/'
```

Edit : changed a little mistake. I've tried it, it works fine.

Comment: No, unfortunately it does nothing :(